Ag-grid compute filtered rows without rendering
I have multiple Ag-grid components in tabs and only one of the tabs is active at a time. When a tab is inactive, the grid is not instantiated at the moment.
My goal is to display a count of how many rows are displayed on each tab even for those tabs that are not active. I don't want to render the grids into the DOM for inactive tabs. Is there a way to create the grid virtually just to apply filters and compute the number of displayed rows, I believe that will be way more performant compared to attaching grid components to DOM.

You need to get the number of records to be displayed on the tab header, for that you are trying to render the grid virtually (and for that you'd need to load the records)? A better approach would be to make a single ajax call to fetch the numbers of records for all the tabs at once from the server itself. Loading of the records can be done when you switch to the respective tab - when the grid would actually render.

We are not using server-side pagination yet. All the filtering is done on the client side. So the count has to be done on the client. But I was trying to avoid having to render the grid in the DOM. It turns out Ag-grid APIs don't have anything that can help me. I have to render the grid to the DOM to be able to get the count. @Paritosh
